# Problem installing Auto-Complete plugin in Emacs

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, plugins

I downloaded Auto-Complete from here: http://github.com/m2ym/auto-complete/downloads, I placed all the files from the .zip file in my load-path `(C:\...Application Data\.emacs.d\plugins\auto-complete-1.0)`, and added the following to my .emacs:

```
;; load auto complete
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/plugins/auto-complete-1.0")
(require 'auto-complete)
(global-auto-complete-mode t)
```

but an error message shows up:

*.emacs:53:1:Error: Cannot open load file: auto-complete*

Comment: Is there an auto-complete.el in that directory?

Comment: Yes, there is auto-complete.el

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a trailing '/' with directory names (as per `file-name-as-directory`). e.g.:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path (file-name-as-directory
                         (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/plugins/auto-complete-1.0")))
```

I rather doubt that's actually an issue, though.

Are your permissions appropriate for those files and directories?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that `~` really expands to `C:\...Application Data`?  Do `C-x d ~ RET` to be sure.

Comment: 'c:/Documents and Settings/Alex.AUTOINSTALL.001/Application Data:
  total used in directory 8 available 29490936' <- yea it does